# C++ setlocale function for Turkish

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<clocale>
using namespace std;


main(){
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");
float kk,bk,cevre,alan;

cout << "Kısa kenarı giriniz:" << endl;
cin >> kk;
cout << "Uzun kenarı giriniz:" << endl;
cin >> bk;

cevre = 2 * (kk + bk);
alan = kk * bk;

cout << "Bu dikdörtgenin çevresi: " << cevre << endl << "Alanı ise : " << alan;



}
```

When i tried to type "ş,ç,İ,ı,ü" it does not work.
And also i tried to include clocale and locale.h libray but it does not work too.

Before i used the "setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish")" function:
I got this :  K─▒sa kenar─▒ giriniz:
After i used it:
KÄ±sa kenarÄ± giriniz:

But i want this output:
Kısa kenarı giriniz:

Comment: Is your terminal or console program set up to handle the same encoding as you use in your strings? I assume it's UTF-8?

Comment: When the stars are aligned (i.e., source code, executing program's locale, console all have the same understanding of the encoding), everything works great.  If any one of those is out of step, the result is *mojibake*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks Your file is in the UTF-8. The default output looks like the CP437 and the Turkish like the CP1254. It looks that You use a Microsoft Windows system.

You can convert Your file to the CP1254.

If You want to stay with the UTF-8, there is no easy way. You can learn about a unicode on Microsoft systems. You can convert output to the terminal encoding. You can try to set terminal to the UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

the key points:

```
Encoding Mismatch: The issue stems from a mismatch between the encoding of your source code file (UTF-8) and the expected encoding of the console (likely CP1254 on Windows).
Potential Solutions:
    Convert File Encoding: You can change the encoding of your file to CP1254 to align with the console. However, this might make collaboration with others who use UTF-8 challenging.
    Adjust Console Encoding: If possible, you can set your terminal to use UTF-8. This would allow you to keep your file in UTF-8, but it might not be feasible on all systems.
    Unicode Support: For more comprehensive Unicode support on Windows, you'll need to explore advanced techniques like using the _setmode function or third-party libraries.
```

Here are additional considerations and recommendations:

```
Editor Encoding: Ensure your text editor is saving the file in the correct encoding (UTF-8 or CP1254, depending on your choice).
Consistency: Choose one encoding approach (either file conversion or console adjustment) and stick with it for consistency.
Cross-Platform Considerations: If you need your code to run on different platforms, using UTF-8 consistently is generally preferred for better compatibility.
Locale Settings: Double-check that your locale settings are correctly set to Turkish using setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish").
Code Clarity: Consider explicitly setting the output stream's encoding using wcout instead of cout for better clarity, especially if you're working with Unicode characters.
```

I hope this helps!